# How do I prove that primary ideals satisfy this property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring.

Let $Q$ be a primary ideal of $R$.

Let $I,J$ be ideals of $R$ such that $IJ\subset Q$.

How do I prove that $I\subset Q$ or $J^n\subset Q$ for some positive integer $n$?

Comment: Do you mean $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $R$ such that $IJ \subset P$?

Comment: @ZeroXLR Yes, wikipedia states that it is a generalized definition of primary ideal to noncommutative rings, but I think this is inconsistent with the standard definition of primary ideals in commutative rings..

Comment: Go ahead. Edit your post to correct the typo.

Comment: @ZeroXLR I didn't notice that. Thank you.